# Running a python program, unsure what the argument is written like?

Tags: python, python-2.7

so i want to run this python program but i am unsure how to run it, when i insert in the arguments it get a token error.

First i "import cw2" which is the file name in the terminal after typing python and then i type in the argument to run a individual task but i get and error. Heres the code, can you tell me how to run the individual parts.

Heres what i typed as the argument cw2 -u user_745409913574d4c6 -d doc_140228202800-6ef39a241f35301a9a42cd0ed21e5fb0 -t task_2, But that doesnt work. Heres the code below showing what the argument is.

```
def main(argv):
user_uuid = ''
doc_uuid = ''
task_id = 0
try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "hu:d:t:", ["user_uuid=", "doc_uuid=", "task_id="])
except getopt.GetoptError:
    print 'cw2 -u <user_uuid> -d <doc_uuid> -t <task_id>'
    sys.exit(2)
for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt == '-h':
        print 'cw2.py -u <user_uuid> -d <doc_uuid> -t <task_id>'
        sys.exit()
    elif opt in ("-u", "--user_uuid"):
        user_uuid = arg
    elif opt in ("-d", "--doc_uuid"):
        doc_uuid = arg
    elif opt in ("-t", "--task_id"):
        task_id = arg
if(int(task_id) == 1):
    with open("../requirements.txt", 'r') as fin:
        print("Requirments.txt file content")
        print fin.read()
if(int(task_id) == 2):
    if(doc_uuid == ''):
        print(" No doc_uuid supplied")
    else:
        task_2(doc_uuid)
        print("Histograms for per country beed saved in : static/results/countries_to_book_UUID.png")
        print("Histograms for per continent beed saved in : static/results/continent_to_book_UUI.png")
elif(int(task_id) == 3):
    task_3()
    print("Histograms of browser usage has been seaved in 'static/results/simple_browser_usage.png' ")
    print("Histograms of generalised browser usage has been seaved in 'static/results/general_browser_usage.png")
elif(int(task_id) == 4):
    print("Data of 10 most active readers")
    task_4(10)
elif(int(task_id) == 5):
    if((user_uuid == '') | (doc_uuid == '')):
        print("Provide user_uuid or/and doc_uuid")
        # 938601f24509a9f1 , 110727005030-000000009cca70787e5fba1fda005c85
    else:
        task_5(user_uuid, doc_uuid)


if __name__ == "__main__":
main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't run it from the Python shell, this is set up to run as a normal program from your terminal.

```
cd <wherever this script is>
chmod a+x ./cw.py
./cw.py -u user_745409913574d4c6 -d doc_140228202800-6ef39a241f35301a9a42cd0ed21e5fb0 -t task_2
```

Also, the indentation is all wrong on the script in your question, but I assume that that's a copy-and-paste error.